# Finding the ancestor's id of a child

Tags: jquery

I am having a Html like ..

```
    <div id="Field1">
        <label id="label1">Name</label><br/>
        <input type="text" data-attr="text" style="width: 200px;" id="input1"/>
        <br/>
        <label id="instr1"/>

        <div class="xfb-row-options1>
          <a class=button-delete src=">- 
          <a title="Add" class="button-add"> +</a>
        </div>
    </div>
```

on clicking on the button delete1  i want to delete the full Div Field1. I want to get to the know the Id of the Parent's parent of button-delete1 that is Field1 . how to get so??

i.e on click of button-delete

```
$(".button-delete1").click(function(){
  // (*)
});
```

(*) Here I want to find the id of Field1 that is the parent holding the class button-   delete so that I can use its id value that is Field1 mainly that 1 and i can delete that DIV fully.

Please suggest me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [`parent()`](http://docs.jquery.com/Traversing/parent) method:

```
(".button-delete1").click(function() {
  alert($(this).parent().parent().attr("id"));
});
```

Answer (score 1):

$(".button-delete1").parent().parent()